# How to access an attribute in a template, besides by its name?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

In an underscore template, is there any other way to access an attribute besides by its name? I've got one called "2a" and I cannot reference it directly, due to its first character being a number. For example, this doesn't work:

```
            <input type="checkbox" name="6a"  <%= 6a ? "checked" : "" %>>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options other than renaming the offending attribute.

Underscore's [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) has a `variable` option:

> By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement. However, you can specify a single variable name with the **variable** setting.

So you could do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="6a"  <%= v['6a'] ? "checked" : "" %>>
```

and this:

```
var t = _.template($('#whatever').html(), null, { variable: 'v' });
var h = t({ '6a': true });​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hBhfu/

You could also wrap it manually when you call the template function:

```
t({ v: { '6a': true  }});
```

You'd use the same template as above in this case.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8AZKw/